# Unity ads not longer working on ios devices only

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityads

I have a game on android and ios, both active on the playstore and appstore with no issues at all (ads work on both just fine). I was working on an update to them and the ads stopped working on ios devices only. There were no changes to the ad code at all. The only difference is that unity was updated to 2018.1.2f1. Ads are enabled in the services panel and test mode is also enabled. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is the code used.

```
void playStandardAd() {
    int randomNum = Random.Range(0, 99);
    if (!lowerAdChances) {
        if (randomNum % 2 == 0 && Advertisement.IsReady()) {
            Advertisement.Show();
        }
    } else {
        lowerAdChances = false;
    }
}

void ShowRewardedVideo() {
    ShowOptions options = new ShowOptions();
    options.resultCallback = HandleShowResult;

    Advertisement.Show("rewardedVideo", options);
}
```

Comment: I know that the server side of Unity Ads had an adjustment made recently, for the sake of GDPR compliance, and there's a possibility that the bug is on their end. (Particularly given Apple's heavy-handed walled-garden approach.) Has anyone else reported an issue like this?

Comment: From what i have read in research, there have been issues but none seemed to be very recent. If it is an issue on the unity ads end, why would it work for the current version on the app store but not the updated version for testing? I have an email out to unity support as well. Curious what they say. Hoping to get it fixed before unity support replies though.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue happened to me yesterday. New SDK didnt work at all. I tried even to create dummy app which had only 1 button to show ad - no luck. Contacted support today, received next response:
"We are experienced some brief downtime yesterday, it should be up again within 2 hours. Can you try it out again? Thanks."

Comment: Did this happen to an app that you are building or that is already on the app store?

Answer (score 0):

Unity support got back to me and said there is a known issue with newer versions of unity. the current work around is to download the unity ads asset and initialize using

```
if (Advertisement.isSupported) {
        Advertisement.Initialize(gameId, true); 
    }
```

where gameId is the id on the unity ads dashboard for iOS and true sets it to test mode.